# Android: dock an widget/app to one side of the display

Tags: android, dockable, archos

Does anybody know how to realise an Android app that docks to one side of the display, is not dragable and no other elements can be dragged over it? I mean something like on the right side of this ARCHOS Android: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpMSs.jpg

Comment: hmm ... I want to have it always on top. Normal applications are lying above normal widgets, which find on the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write your own custom firmware. SDK applications cannot do this.

Comment: Ok I assumed that already. Does anybody know about example codes for similar problems?

Comment: @yildi: Historically, StackOverflow has not been terribly useful for Android firmware development questions. You may wish to try some site or list dedicated to Android firmware development.